# How to write a regular expression for specific word?

Tags: java, regex

I have a txt file that contains hexadecimal values on it. I have a program that can read the file and display the regular expression output. But i need to search through FFD8FFE0 and grab the content till FFD9. Normally i have write w[A-Za-z0-9 ]+ as the regular expression. How can i write the regular expression for this (i want to grab content between above parameters). my usual reg-ex does not work in this pattern. Please send me any suggestion regular expression. My hexadecimal txt file contains like   FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 02 00 (this format).

Comment: Have you tried any other regexes or read the regex documentation?

Comment: i am new to regular expressions. In my project this is a one part. I have managed to write regex for other patterns. I am struggel when writing a regex to a constent string (eg: name, address)

Comment: Then do some reading and research about it - there is lots of information online about how to create regular expressions. If you ask other people to do things for you, you don't learn them properly, so you have to keep on asking others for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to share my answer with the other users who is interest in this question. my regular expression was " FF D8 FF E0 \w[A-Za-z0-9 ]+ FF D9". This regular expression was successfully worked.